# Ansible error - No Authentication Handler found:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

i am trying to download a file from s3 bucket , i did aws configure and also exported my access key and secret key but i am still getting the same error. Please suggest me

**Code:**

```
- name: Download xx tarball
  s3:
      bucket: xxx
      object: folder/xx-commandline-4.0.3.tar.gz
      dest: '/tmp/{{ xx_tarball }}'
      mode: get
  when: 'st.stat.exists == false'
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No Authentication Handler found: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials "}


ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2



uname -a
Linux ip-xx-xxx-xx-x 4.4.0-1026-aws #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 21:59:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Ensure that you creds do work with aws-cli first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check couple of things:

I- `boto` is installed on the target host, where you need to download the file from s3:

```
sudo -H pip install boto
```

II- If this is remote host then use this format:

```
- name: Download xx tarball
  s3:
    aws_access_key: "{{ AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY }}"
    bucket: xxx
    object: folder/xx-commandline-4.0.3.tar.gz
    dest: '/tmp/{{ xx_tarball }}'
    mode: get
  when: st.stat.exists == false
```

Note: when you export the AWS credentials, it work locally but not for the remote host, so you need to pass the credentials to the module so it will work for remote host.

Hope it might help you